# What is the default selection in an Excel pivot table

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I have come across numerous definitions of how Excel adds the field into a pivot table when selected, for example:

> You can quickly add fields to your pivot table by using the check box next to the field name from the field list in the PivotTable Fields window. This can save time if you have a lot of fields to add instead of dragging and dropping each item. Fields containing text data will be added to the Rows section and fields containing numeric data will be added to the Values section when using the check box.

Source: [howtoexcel](https://www.howtoexcel.org/pivot-tables/pivot-table-tips-and-tricks/).

However, here's a ten-second video showing that this is wrong -- at least in my case using Excel on Mac:

https://gyazo.com/f299b74d6f6fa4d74737e3f88362538c

[image]

Adding a float does a sum (makes sense), adding a text field does a count (??), adding an integer does a row aggregation (??), and adding a date does a count (??). Other than summing up a float, which would be common for financial purposes, I'm not sure what the rhyme or reason is for the defaults on everything else. Is there definitive documentation on what the default selection is by excel or more info on how this is done?

Comment: Is there a specific reason/catalyst for this question, or just curiosity?

Comment: Just tested it on Excel 365 on Windows and Name and Date get auto added to Rows, whilst Age and Numbers go to Values (both grouped into sum)

Comment: @Jerry -- thanks. Two questions here: (1) Is there any documentation on the defaults? (2) What's "Excel 365"? My version shows that too (the license type), but the version is Version 16.32 for Mac?

Comment: @BigBen related to a javascript pivot-builder outside of Excel.

Comment: @David542 Hmm, I could find only [this one](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-a-pivottable-to-analyze-worksheet-data-a9a84538-bfe9-40a9-a8e9-f99134456576) which looks official, but then again, it doesn't match the behaviour I experience on my Excel version, and yes Excel 365 is the major version (the minor version for mine is 16.0.10730.20426). There's Excel 2000, Excel 2004, Excel 2008, and so on if I recall correctly. My guess would be that yours is a newer version. But you raised a good point about that inconsistency, which probably isn't documented.

Comment: @Jerry -- thanks, which section can I find the mention of the defaults when added in?

Comment: @Jerry -- Oh, I see: `In the Field Name area at the top, select the check box for any field you want to add to your PivotTable. By default, non-numeric fields are added to the Row area, date and time fields are added to the Column area, and numeric fields are added to the Values area.` But that's totally different than mine, or yours too it seems.

Comment: @David542 yep, leave it to microsoft to leave things unclear ^^;